# Enable typing in Windows text fields?

Tags: windows, typing

I can't type (i.e. nothing happens) in these Windows text fields like the Search field:
[image]

I know this is because I once have turned off a service or something that is necessary for it, but I don't remember which one.

Answer (score 0):

`ctfmon.exe` was missing/not running.